# Understanding ECMAScript implicit semicolons and whitespace parsing

Tags: javascript, coding-style, whitespace, ecmascript-5

I've seen, very often in fact, this cited as why to use K&R style when writing ECMAScript.

```
function foo () {
  return
    {
      foo: 1
    }
  ;
}
```

That doesn't work in ECMAScript or Javascript: implicit-semicolon addition results in the function returning `undefined`. However I see this all the time too

```
function bar () {
  var a = "BAR";
  return a
    .toLowerCase()
  ;
}
```

And, I'm wondering why implicit semicolons doesn't result in that returning `"BAR"`, why does `bar` get returned there?

Comment: I realize it's basically what your question is about, but the whitespace use here is hideous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the syntax doesn't work with an implicit semicolon at the end of the line.

If you add the semicolon:

```
function bar () {
  var a = "BAR";
  return a;
    .toLowerCase()
  ;
}
```

you would get a syntax error on the next line.